# "Ordered" scan with regexp

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a String my_string :

```
[...]
THE_PREFIX value1 THE_SUFFIX
THE_PREFIX value2 THE_SUFFIX
[...]
```

And I want to get each value ( value1, value2, ...). I tried

`my_string.scan(/THE_PREFIX (.*) THE_SUFFIX/m)`

but it returns only one String :

```
value1 THE_SUFFIX THE_PREFIX value2
```

How could I do that ?

**EDIT**

Each value contains a lot of special chars. I don't want to do the regexp that match with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reluctant regex quantifier:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = "THE_PREFIX value1 THE_SUFFIX
irb(main):002:0" THE_PREFIX value2 THE_SUFFIX"
=> "THE_PREFIX value1 THE_SUFFIX\nTHE_PREFIX value2 THE_SUFFIX"
irb(main):003:0> a.scan(/THE_PREFIX (.*) THE_SUFFIX/m)
=> [["value1 THE_SUFFIX\nTHE_PREFIX value2"]]
irb(main):004:0> a.scan(/THE_PREFIX (.*?) THE_SUFFIX/m)
=> [["value1"], ["value2"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is too loose:

```
my_string.scan(/THE_PREFIX (\w+) THE_SUFFIX/m)
```

Returns:

```
my_string.scan(/THE_PREFIX (\w+) THE_SUFFIX/m)
=> [["value1"], ["value2"]]
```

Flatten it if you want a single array:

```
my_string.scan(/THE_PREFIX (\w+) THE_SUFFIX/m).flatten
=> ["value1", "value2"]
```

Comment: sorry, `value1` was an example. It's a lot of chars & special chars. I don't want to do the regexp that match with this

Comment: It always helps for you to put accurate examples of what you are looking for. Please update your question to be more accurate.